# Links e conteúdo na mesma página sem frames

Tags: css, html5

Estou criando um site simples, baseado apenas em HTML5 e CSS3, nele estão duas colunas, uma sendo um `<nav>` para conter os links, e o outro sendo uma `<section>` para conter o conteúdo.

Ao clicar em um dos links do lado da coluna `<nav>`, este deve abrir o documento seja ele qual for no lado da `<section>` na mesma página, sem ir para outra página, sem uso de JavaScript ou qualquer outra ferramenta, apenas HTML5 e CSS3.

Sem os frames é possível? Qual seria o código?

Comment: O que você já fez ? Posta o código aí. Mas já vou te avisando que apenas HTML5 e CSS3 não faz isso. Tem que ter **JavaScript** com **Ajax**.

Comment: Sugiro que faça com `frames` mesmo, você vai ganhar mais tempo e acredito que mais desempenho.

Comment: O título muda, mas a resposta é sempre a mesma. Existem muitas perguntas no site sobre "navegação sem refresh" no site.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly pra que isso, mano ? Usar frames ? Muito arcaico...

Comment: @Gumball se funciona e supri a necessidades não existe um porque não usar, se da pra fazer só com HTML pra que usar ajax? ;)

Comment: Mas se dá pra fazer com ajax pra que usar HTML ? kkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Usando Javascript é possível, e usando frameworks javascript fica muito mais fácil. Vou recomendar o [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) ou o [W3.CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp) ambos frameworks oferecem opções para navegação da forma que deseja.

Como existem estas e outras opções não vou postar códigos aqui. Pesquise na internet sobre estes assuntos ou os frameworks e se tiver dúvidas mais específicas sobre um ou outro poste aqui.